# Can't select matched input from google places autocomplete when bootstrap input has input button add on

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I'm trying to get an input field with button add on working with googles place finder (autocomplete feature).

Everything works fine until the input field has an add-on. There are no scripts errors in the debugging console. Just that nothing happens when selecting from the autocomplete suggestion.

I'm using latest jQuery, Bootstrap 3.2 and google maps v 3.

I've been scratching my head all-night on this. can someone please suggest something?